# Payment validation got VERIFIED for web_accept transaction type but not for subscr_signup

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

We have been using "Post to return page" (rm = 2) as the way of receiving payment data for regular one time purchase (web_accept) and we have been getting "VERIFIED" fine when doing the validation. Recently we want to add a subscription-based product so I have been testing in the paypal sandbox and I am really baffled about what I did wrong for always getting INVALID when validating subscriptions (subscr_signup). The regular purchases returned VERIFIED in the sandbox just fine but not the subscriptions. It is the exact same piece of code for posting the validation, the same merchant/buyer combination...etc. Did I miss anything? Below is the common classic ASP code snippets which I have used. Please advise. Thanks

```
' read post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
str = Request.Form & "&cmd=_notify-validate"

' post back to PayPal system to validate
'set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
' set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHttp.Send str
```

Comment: Check what you are receiving and posting back and make sure they are the same and no additional information is being added aside from validate part.

Comment: I did check and that's why the validation for regular purchase worked. I am frustrated that the same piece of validation code doesn't work for the subscription signups.

Answer (score 0):

There are some IPN issues that are currently effecting the live site.  This issue that you are reporting sounds like it may be related to the issues.  I would suggest opening up a ticket with [PayPal's Merchant Technical Support](http://www.paypal.com/mts) team.  This way we can look into the issue further and also notify you once the issue is resolved.